# How can I adjust the spacing between buttons in vaadin?

Tags: css, sass, vaadin

I am new to the Vaadin framework.I'm now trying to learn it by rebuilding the demo on their front page of Quciktickets dashboard using the Eclipse vaadin plug-in. Now I'm using css in my Theme to configure the sidebar part of that page.

My problem is after I add the buttons in the sidebar, they seems to be too far away from each other. So how can I fix it? I've tried to use padding, but that will only change the size of the button block while I wanna change the spacing between the blocks. Thx for anyone paying attention or giving hints for such a noob question.

code define the `nativebutton` layout:

```
.sidebar .sidemenu .v-nativebutton {
-webkit-appearance: none;
display: block;
padding: 10px 14px 10px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
margin: 0;
/*position: relative;*/

border-top: 1px solid #4b4c4d;
border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,.05);
border-bottom: 1px solid #353637;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,.18);
background:transparent;
color: #888a8c;
font-weight: normal;
text-shadow: 0 1px  0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
text-align:center;  
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the margin instead of padding? Also an example code or the actual link would help.

Comment: But margin was set to 0

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual website? The CSS alone is not useful in this case.

Comment: I think your problem is in the layout that contains the buttons so some code is needed to solve your issue.

Comment: I have the same problem right now. I think what Derek means is similiar to what you get from "undefined width layout", but for height. See [link](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html) - 6.3.2, ie. stack the buttons on top of each other, with little or no margin between them. Can this be done in java code, without getting your hands dirty with CSS?

Comment: @Roger Thx，your link is pretty helpful.Good solution for such problem in vaddin